# Is it possible to enable key repeat for letter keys on the Apple Smart Keyboard for iPad Pro?

Tags: ipad, keyboard, smart-keyboard

The key repeat options in iOS Keyboard settings seem to work for the navigation keys (arrows, backspace, etc) but not for the letter keys. When I hold down a letter key, it does not repeat. Is it possible to change this behavior to allow all keys to repeat like on a regular desktop keyboard?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell this isn't possible, which is a shame. I was trying to use my iPad with remote desktop where I need to hold down keys and it just doesn't work. It seems this is a "feature" of iOS that only certain keys like space and delete are allowed to repeat. Here are some links about it that I found.

https://discussions.apple.com/message/34220222#34220222

https://support-splashtoppersonal.splashtop.com/hc/en-us/articles/230005527-Does-Splashtop-support-Bluetooth-keyboards-